# Add a link to my iPhone app before submission ("Catch 22")

Tags: ios, facebook

I use the Facebook API for iOS, which enables posting content to the Facebook wall. The API allows custom links to be added next to "Like" and "Comment". I would like to add "Get App" here which links to my app on App Store, but how do I do this when my App ID will not be known to be before the app is actually approved? ("Chicken-and-egg" situation)

Possible solutions:

A) Link to a temporary URL which is changed to the App Store link after approval

B) Wait until version 1.1 to add this, when the App ID is known

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an App ID once you create an app in iTunes Connect. That means you get the ID before you publish the app and it doesn't change when the app goes trough review or publishing process. I'm not able to make a screenshot right now, but it's easily found in top left corner when you click on manage apps > your app.

Comment: So you can get the app ID prior to submission? That's great! That solves my issue!

Comment: Or you could always use the URL format http://itunes.com/apps/AppName, which will work nicely even without the ID (the URL forwards to the correct one though, so it's a bit slower than usual).

Answer (score 0):

Some ISPs and independent providers offer domain name services that would help here, possibly.

I use EasyDNS, but there are other options.

The idea is that you register a domain name with them and purchase a plan that includes web forwarding.  Web forwarding lets you send any web traffic for your domain to a specific URL.

You temporarily forward to any URL you like (presumably a page on your regular site, maybe a "Coming soon" page).  Then, when you receive the real URL, change the forwarding to point there.

It might take a day or so for the change to percolate across the while interweb, but generally you can see and test results fairly quickly yourself, or at least that's been my experience.